# Getting seperate values from table with one binary field

Tags: php, mysql

I have table for student attendance like below:

```
id | Present | date
1  | 1
1  | 0
1  | 1
1  | 1
1  | 0
```

Now I want to get the total days he is present via single query. Is it possible?

Below is the way I used to get the student present/absent count:

```
select count(*) from table where present =1 
select count(*) from table where present =0
```

But I think can I get both from one query instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(present = 1) as present1,
       sum(present = 0) as present0
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
select (select count(*) from table where present=1) as "present"
      , (select count(*) from table where present=0) as "absent";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this its working fine :**

```
SELECT SUM( present =1 ) AS present, SUM( present =0 ) AS absent
FROM details
WHERE id =1
```

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
For all student with group by

```
select id,present,absent from
(
    select id,sum(case when present = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as present,
        sum(case when present = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as absent
    from table_name
    group by id
) as absen
```

if you want to show only one student, just add `where clause` in the end like this :

```
select id,present,absent from
(
    select id,sum(case when present = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as present,
        sum(case when present = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as absent
    from table_name
    group by id
) as absen
where id = '1'
```

Hope this help you..